# Approval process email current approver

Tags: approval-process, org

I am trying to send an email to the current approver to an approval process.

From the approval process's page I select Add New->Email Alert.

From there I cannot find a way to select the current approver as a recipient. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest below steps:

1. Create a custom field of type "Email".
2. When record is submitted for approval populate this field with approver email address.
3. Select Email Fields for email alert.
   [image]

Comment: Thank you, seems like the only possible way to do it as I couldn't find anything else!